# Deploying Geoserver on Tomcat in Windows

Tags: tomcat, geoserver

I want to run geoserver on tomcat, so i downloaded the geoserver.war file and i deployed in tomcat. But while clicking on geoserver it is showing Error "HTTP status 404"
[image: first image]

[image: second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBTfV.png)[enter image description here]

Can you help me how to sove this?

Tomcat9-stderr log File:
2017-10-03 11:17:53 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.220 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M26
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.222 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Aug 2 2017 20:29:05 UTC
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.222 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.0.0
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.222 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 7
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.222 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.1
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.222 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.222 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_141
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.222 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_141-b15
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.222 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.222 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.222 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.222 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.223 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.223 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.223 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.223 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\logging.properties
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.223 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.geotools.referencing.forceXY=true
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.223 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.geotoools.render.lite.scale.unitCompensation=true
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.223 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: exit
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.223 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms128m
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.223 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx256m
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.223 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\apps\FME\;C:\Program Files\Hexagon\ERDAS IMAGINE 2015\;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Scripts\;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\site-packages;;.]
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.316 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.379 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.381 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.382 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.382 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 420 ms
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.402 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.402 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M26
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.418 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver.war]
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.628 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver.war] has finished in [209] ms
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.628 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs]
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.642 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs] has finished in [14] ms
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.642 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager]
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.665 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager] has finished in [23] ms
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.666 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT]
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.678 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [12] ms
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.680 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.686 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
03-Oct-2017 11:17:54.688 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 305 ms

Comment: Add tomcat log file like catalina or stdouterr

Comment: i have attached the screen shot of catalina and strerr log file

Comment: a screenshot is no use at all - please include some actual text, preferably the bit showing where GeoServer is starting up.

Comment: i have attached the log file of tomcat_stderr.out file.